# Axios Get Request not going to Correct URL

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-router

I have the proxy set as http://localhost:8000/api (works fine for other requests)

In react I'm using axios for a get request:

```
const res = username 
            ? await axios.get("posts/profile/"+username)
            : await axios.get("posts/timeline/6120b0e07ea0361eb4982b1c");
```

when the username is not defined the second condition works, but when the username is provided, the first condition sends request to another url:
in VSCode Terminal where backend is running this is visible:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2021:15:38:12 +0000] "GET /api/profile/posts/profile/matt HTTP/1.1" 404 169
```

It should go to **/api/posts/profile/matt** but instead it goes to the above one

In chrome console:

```
xhr.js:210 GET http://localhost:3000/profile/posts/profile/matt 404 (Not Found)
```

In POSTMAN the api works. When I use the full URL in like:

```
const res = username 
            ? await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/posts/profile/"+username)
            : await axios.get("posts/timeline/6120b0e07ea0361eb4982b1c");
```

After using the full url the app works fine, but it should work properly when without the full URL as I have already set the proxy and it works fine for other get requests, even the timeline one works well without the full url.

Here is the code for react routes:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          <Register />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile/:username">
          <Profile />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

and here are the APIs(they work fine when used with correct URL):

```
//GET TIMELINE POSTS
router.get("/timeline/:userId", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
        const userPosts = await Post.find({ userId: currentUser._id });
        
        const friendPosts = await Promise.all(
            currentUser.following.map( friendId => {
                return Post.find({ userId: friendId });
            })
        );

        res.status(200).json(userPosts.concat(...friendPosts));

    } catch( err ) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});

//GET User's all POSTS
router.get("/profile/:username", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        
        const user = await User.findOne({username: req.params.username});
        const posts = await Post.find({userId: user._id});
        
        res.status(200).json(posts);
        
    } catch( err ) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});
```

What can be the issue here? The problem is only happening with the profile request(sends request to wrong url)

Comment: where does the `/api` path come into play? Are you using a reverse proxy on the server? and on which route are you serving the front-end?

Comment: the proxy  is: http://localhost:8000/api, all request except the profile one work fine, please refer this ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69592894/is-react-router-messing-with-the-api-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a slash before posts worked:

```
await axios.get("/posts/profile/"+username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relative URL is resolved differently than you think. You could debug this, but I would recommend just using absolute URLs to ensure you know how they resolve:

```js
const res = username 
  ? await axios.get("/api/posts/profile/"+username)
  : await axios.get("/api/posts/timeline/6120b0e07ea0361eb4982b1c");
```

Comment: when I add /api before /posts, the timeline request also stops working and sends request to /api/api/posts/timeline/6120b0e07ea0361eb4982b1c, all the requests **except** the **profile** one work without using the absolute URL that is "http:localhost:8000/api/posts/profile/matt"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions, you can also use ticks ( ` ) which allow you to do the following:

```
await axios.get(`/posts/profile/${username}`);
```