# Is react-router messing with the API Url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, react-router

I have a API that works fine, but when i use it with react, the get request goes to

```
/api/profile/posts/profile/matt
```

whereas it should go to:

```
/api/posts/profile/matt
```

The proxy is set on `localhost:8000/api`, that works fine for the other APIs when is working with react.

Code for calling the APIs(Only profile one doesn't work, rest all work fine, even the profile one works when I use the absolute URL):

```
const res = username 
            ? await axios.get("posts/profile/"+username)
            : await axios.get("posts/timeline/6120b0e07ea0361eb4982b1c");
```

code for routes:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          <Register />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile/:username">
          <Profile />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

I have similar problem with this user as well: [How to prevent React-router from messing up your API url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178509/how-to-prevent-react-router-from-messing-up-your-api-url)

Comment: React Router does partial matching. Define the routes as `exact`, or change the routes names.

Comment: Where are you telling react to look for the /api/…? Maybe you have it in a constant in the service…adding exact to the route should work fine

Comment: I have tried adding **exact** but it doesn't work, the proxy in package.json is set as 
localhost:8000/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call an API, you need to pass a full path URL to the `fetch` or `axios` to work properly, but there are some points that need to be mentioned.

All APIs have two parts: a base URL (which is not changing) + other parts

For example:
`https://someAddress.com/api/posts/profile/matt`

The base URL is `https://someAddress.com/api/` here.

The Axios take a `baseURL` parameter to call your API's without specifying on every API call:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://somwAddress.com/api/;
```

Now, simply call your API:

```
axios.get("posts/profile/" + username)
```

It requests to the full URL: `https://someAddress.com/api/posts/profile/username`

Comment: setting the base URL **WORKED**, what I'm still confused about is why do we need to set the baseURL when I have already defined the proxy in package.json (which works with other get/post requests in the application except the get profile posts one), anyways Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the full URL in axios.get() method.
for example- "HTTP://localhost:port/api_path".

Why only profile API messing with you because you have a profile route mentioned in your router

```
    <Route path="/profile/:username">
        <Profile />
    </Route>
```

You are not using any wild card routes if you would have It would create problem with every api

Comment: isn't using the full path usually discouraged? how I can I fix this so that the request goes to the correct path without using the absolute URL?

Comment: I actually have a problem with using the full path at the development level, so you will have to change all your Axios request before production.